# DotNet Highcharts: labelling the inside pie of a donut

Tags: dotnethighcharts

I'm using DotNet.HighCharts and am very pleased with what it enables me to do so far. However, I cannot get it to position labels on the inside of a donut / pie chart. It appears that the distance attribute is not available for the DataLabels. Does anyone have a workround?

Alternatively, does anone know how to write text onto the top of a chart at a specific position (relative to the container of course)?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use Distance property in the DataLabels:

```
DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
{
    Formatter = "function() { return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null; }",
    Color = Color.White,
    Distance = -30
}
```

Also you can see how is used in the sample project. Download from here: http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases